# Ctrl + Click on function name does not navigate to declaration or usages in JetBrains Gateway

Tags: go, jetbrains-ide, keymapping, keymaps

I'm using JetBrains Gateway with Go plugin in IntelliJ client.
<kbd>Ctrl + Click</kbd> on function name doesn't navigate to function definition, or function usage, but pops up a balloon instead.

Current case:
Clicking method name-> pops up a balloon notification -> Show Options -> Find -> displays usages.
[image]

Wanted scenario:
[image]

I tried to reset the keymap to default.